# Unexpected behavior from bind

Tags: jquery

Rather than getting a click bind, I'm getting a list of console messages, as though Javascript is executing the bind's action right away instead of creating a bind:

```
var biomes = new Array("glacier","desert","forest","grassland","hills","jungle","mountains","ocean","plains","swamp","tundra");


function changeTerrain(biome){
  console.log(biome);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // fill in terrain guide
    $.each(biomes,function(x,biome){
      $('div#terrainGuide').append("<div class='tile "+biome+"'></div>");
      $('div#terrainGuide:last-child').bind({
        click: changeTerrain(biome)
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an anonymous function in the bind call, i.e.:

```
 click: changeTerrain(biome)
```

should become

```
 click: function(){ changeTerrain(biome); }
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be binding the same event handler to *all* of the elements that you are appending when you need to only bind once.

```
$.each(biomes,function(x,biome){
  $('div#terrainGuide').append("<div class='tile "+biome+"'></div>");
});

$('div#terrainGuide:last-child').bind({
    click: function(){
       changeTerrain(biome);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was trying to bind once to each of the div.tile. You set me on the right path:
`
    `$.each(biomes,function(x,biome){
      $('div#terrainGuide').append("<div class='tile "+biome+"'></div>");
      $('div#terrainGuide div.tile:last-child').bind({
        click: function(){changeTerrain(biome)}
      });
    });
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have the behavior you want with this:

```
var biomes = new Array("glacier","desert","forest","grassland","hills","jungle","mountains","ocean","plains","swamp","tundra");

function changeTerrain(e){
  //gets the clicked child by calling e.target, and an small hack to get the child's biome
  console.log($(e.target).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // fill in terrain guide
    $.each(biomes,function(x,biome){
      $('div#terrainGuide').append("<div class='tile "+biome+"'>"+biome+"</div>");
    });
   //remove the bind from the loop and binds the click event to all .tile elements, which are #terrainGuide children
   $("div.tile").click(changeTerrain);
});
```